# Generating SSRS reports using C# program

Tags: c#, reporting-services, report

I have a situation where I need to generate SSRS report for each account holder. The vague idea that I am having is to write a C# Code that should get the list of account numbers as input and run the report for each account number and then store the report as a pdf in a location, that can be mailed to the respective account holders. Now I have an SSRS report that can run by inputting one account number. But how can I run this report in a kind of a loop for list of account numbers. Do I need to write a c# program that should in someway call the reports for each account number( and obviously this program should run at a specific time say 8P.M every day for instance). Is this idea possible to implement? I am totally struck at this point. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well. I googled and figured out that what I might need is an SSRS data driven subscription. But when I created one and scheduled to run at say 8P.M, its not running. And its not showing any error message in the description.

Comment: Well I guess this is pretty late reply but refer this [Old Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12459092/ssrs-2008-subreport-for-each-value-from-multi-valued-parameter) that might be helpful in case.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but possibly still relevant.

Two possible workarounds:

1. Write a C# program to call the ReportExecutionService webservice in a loop. You can call SetExecutionParameters() each time with an array of report parameters.
2. Write a C# program to use WebClient.DownloadFile in a loop with the url of the report. Report parameters can be part of the url.