# SSRS 2008 - Subreport for each value from multi-valued parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, subreport

using SSRS 2008 R2 and wondering, if is possible to generate sub-report for each value selected in multi-valued parameter?

Lets imagine you have multi-valued parameter "parameterA" with four values selected (Value1, Value2, Value3 and Value4). I'd like to generate sub-report for each of these values (passing the value as single parameter). Sure, I can change the procedure to handle multi-valued parameter, but because of performance and caching I really don't want to.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this you would have to put the subreport into a list or tablix. As far as I know there's no easy way to have that list or tablix iterate over the values in a multi-valued parameter. It will only accept a dataset.

So the only workaround I can think of involves splitting the parameter into a set of rows in a dataset, which is possible but not trivial with SQL. However, if the available values for the parameter come from a dataset the situation would improve: you can just hook the tablix/list to your dataset and filter items that aren't selected in the parameter.

**Edit:**  I've found a slightly hackish solution to **expanding a multi-valued parameter into a dataset**, by building the dataset query as an expression. Assuming a parameter `@MultiParamX` this expression will create a query that outputs all selected values in one column:

```vb
="SELECT '" 
&
 Join(Parameters!MultiParamX.Value, "' MyParam UNION ALL SELECT '")
&
"' MyParam"
```

This may generate a query such as the following (reformatted for readability):

```sql
SELECT 'A' MyParam
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B' MyParam
UNION ALL
SELECT 'C' MyParam
-- Etc. for all selected values
```

This will generate a result set such as:

```
┌─────────┐
│ MyParam │
├─────────┤
│ A       │
│ B       │
│ C       │
│ Etc.    │
└─────────┘
```

Comment: Hi Jeroen, thanks for your answer, you're right. In case parameter comes from dataset, it's simple actually. Only thing to mention is to use filter instead of visibility, to avoid unnecessary procedure calls.

Comment: I've updated my answer to suggest filtering instead of using visibility.