# How do I print multiple duplicate "named" copies of a report in SSRS 2008? eg, "ORIGINAL", "CUSTOMER COPY", etc

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I want to be able to have a multi-value parameter called CopyTypes, which would contain values such as:

```
{ "ORIGINAL", "CUSTOMER COPY", "PACKING LIST" }
```

I would like the report to create an identical page for each value in my parameter array, only changing a single text variable in the page footer for each page.

I had thought of just using a single value parameter and calling the report in code once for each param, but this solution isn't ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a setup that may work for you:

- Create a subreport for the "single page" with a fixed height
- In the subreport, create a parameter "FooterText"
- Display the parameter at the *bottom* of the page (footers of subreports don't show up)
- Create a parent report, with that subreport in a list
- Create a dataset that generates a row for each selected value in the parameter
- Pass that dataset's values as a parameter to the subreport

See [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12461136/419956) on how you could convert the selected values to a dataset.

Bottom line is that you can't really relate stuff in the header/footer of a report to the content of a page: they're quite "static" in that regard. This is particularly a problem for the *footer* (and also in my suggestion above), because if you "fake" a footer in the report body it may be "shoved off" the page if the body content grows. If that's a problem it may be worth to consider a workaround, and place the text in the ("fake") header e.g. at the top of the subreport.