# Is it possible to run a single record report on Multiple records from a view?

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report that pulls in a sub report and is run from within a single record on Dynamics CRM 2011. The report is built in SSRS 2008. It uses a parameter to find the id of the current record. The report runs fine from within each record which is what we need it to do.

There is now a requirement to also run the same report for multiple records, in essence printing out the results 1 record per page for multiple records.

I have tried to copy the report and sub report (making the relevant changes), find the multiple records list in an advanced find view, and then run the report on all the selected records in the view but instead of pulling the details for each record onto a single page and then the next record onto the next page, this method pulls all results for each field from all records and then all the results from all records into the next field.

I am assuming that the parameter that is in the original version single report to find the current record, when used with the advanced find list is pulling all of the id's for all of the records and then producing all of the results per field.
I have gone around in circles trying multiple ways of ending up with a report per record per page but I now need some help.  If I remove the current id parameter I cannot work out how the report would pull the correct information together for each single record and the matching sub-report before moving onto the next record.

Is it possible to batch print a single report on multiple records selected from an advanced find view? and if so please could someone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're report is set up but you'll probably want to use a **list** to separate each instance of the report. Set it to Group by your ID field.

Then you put your current report items that you want generated for each item inside the list. The list will generate an instance for each ID.

It's a bit complicated sounding at first but not too difficult once you get the idea.

[MSDN - Lists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239330%28v=sql.120%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

[SSRS generate same report for multiple values accepted as parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21603047/ssrs-generate-same-report-for-multiple-values-accepted-as-parameters)

The list is like a rectangle that repeats.

Comment: Thank you.  That makes sense.  I will read up on it now and try that.

Comment: Using a list was the answer.  I moved all of the items sideways in my report, pulled in a list item, expanded it, and then pulled my items back inside the list item, making sure that everything fitted.   It now runs within the advanced find view using the selected records as the parameters except that my sub-report is not showing but that is for another question. So thank you for the heads up and also thank you for the learning experience as I had not used lists before.

Comment: Just in case anyone else gets the same issue with sub-reports - I deleted the sub-report item from the main report and pulled in a new sub-report item, right clicked on the sub-report item, pulled in the sub-report name and the variable and then saved and it worked correctly. So I hadnt changed anything, just did it again as we have to sometimes in SSRS.